file permission error when using a xtrabackup container to backup mysql in docker
My web app is deployed with docker compose. In order to backup data I add an xtrabackup container as the follow:
  mysql_backup:
    image: perconalab/percona-xtrabackup:8.4.0-1
    container_name: mysql_backup
    volumes:
      - './mysql/db:/var/lib/mysql'
      - './backup:/tmp/backup'
    depends_on:
      - ferry_mysql

  ferry_mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: ferry_mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'xxx'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'app'
      MYSQL_USER: 'app'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'xxx'
    volumes:
      - './mysql/db:/var/lib/mysql'

Then I open a bash with the container and start to backup with the following commands:
docker compose run mysql_backup bash
xtrabackup --backup --host=ferry_mysql --target-dir=/tmp/backup/data --data-dir=/var/lib/mysql --user=root --password=xxx

Then I get the following error
2024-11-05T07:25:23.460993-00:00 0 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
2024-11-05T07:25:23.461034-00:00 0 [ERROR] [MY-012595] [InnoDB] The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.
2024-11-05T07:25:23.461043-00:00 0 [ERROR] [MY-013861] [InnoDB] Failed to list redo log files in the redo log directory ./#innodb_redo/


I would move this question and its answer to the dba.stackexchange.com sister site of SO as it has nothing to do with programming or software development, but configuring a backup service for a containerised mysql.

@Shadow I am not sure about this. It's not just a dba thing IMO and the fix require not only dba knowledge but also docker and linux.

Linux is operating system, docker is to create a containerised environment. None of these are directly programming related. you are setting permissions via supplying switches to readily available tools. No coding is involved.

Turn out it is the user permission issue. Files in /var/lib/mysql is owned by user 999, and id $(whami) shows the current user is mysql(1001).
To fix this issue I add -u option to the docker run to run bash as user 999:
docker compose run -u 999 mysql_backup bash

